# Hyperledger fabric nodejs sdk returns success message even if orderers are down

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric node.js sdk. I did an experiment on the network and sdk. I put all the orderers down and performed a write operation using sdk.

It returned a success response with the payload. I was shocked. The orderers were down. I verified the couchdb and there was not any record that I was trying to write neither the block contains that record. My question is why it gave me success response while it should give me an error response.

Any explaination??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you should know the process of a `write operation`.

A Fabric write transaction usually happens in two steps:

1. endorse
2. commit

Fabric SDK will send your request to peers during endorse step, this is done by SDK api `Channel.sendTransactionProposal`, and peer will exec the transaction and response R&W set and signatures. By now Fabric will not commit your transaction to ledger or state db.

After SDK get all success responses, SDK will gather all the endorsement response as well the endorsement proposal, send them to the orderer. this is done by SDK channel api `Channel.sendTransaction`, this step did commit the transaction to the ledger and state db.